# Installing CWM without android sdk

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

**Any software that'll help installing CWM**

Is there any software that will allow me to install CWM other than android sdk.
For some reason I am not able to install android sdk.

Answer (score 1):

You can flash CWM or TWRP directly from your phone using an app called **[Rashr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.recoverytools)**. You can also choose to download the IMG files if you don't have them. Make sure you flash a compatible and stable version of the recovery.

Answer (score 1):

You have to root your device and need an internet connection (3G or Wifi) to install CWM from your device.
Download [Rom Manager.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en)
Your Device must be connected to internet. Open Application.
Select First Option in that app, Recovery Setup.
Then Select ClockworkMod Recovery from install or update recovery coloumn. Confirm your phone model and boot into your recovery.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't list my device